# Mentions don't notify users and aren't highlighted

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I have been testing Discord.js with Typescript recently and just wanted to do a simple command which pings the user, but that doesn't happen, it only mentions them.

Here's the code I want to get working:

```
run: async (client: Client, interaction: CommandInteraction) => {
    const content = `${interaction.member?.user}`;

    await interaction.followUp({
        content
    });
}
```

The resulting message does contain a mention which is clickable, but the message isn't highlighted. I even tried mentioning via Discord ID directly, but that does the same thing (meaning a clickable mention, but no highlighting or notification). Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the error here? `${interaction.member?.user}` will mention the user (ie add a clickable link) but if there is no interaction sent or deferred, `interaction.followUp` will throw an error.

Comment: Perhaps I worded it incorrectly, this is not the code in its entirety, the issue isn't with `interaction.followUp` the issue is the mention doesn't throw a notification and is only treated as the "clickable link".

Answer (score -1):

you have to put user id like this
`<@${userId}>`
then it will mention that user